# How to make more than 1000 requests per second through Gatling?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I am using the following setup which generates more than 3000 rps. Requirement is to test with up to 4k rps.

The setup that I am using is:

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(8) during(10 minutes)).protocols(httpConf)).throttle(
  reachRps(1000) in (20 seconds),
  holdFor(5 minute),
  jumpToRps(2000),
  holdFor(5 minute)
)
```

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
17:18:15.603 [gatling-http-thread-1-1] WARN  i.gatling.http.ahc.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Home' failed: j.n.ConnectException: handshake timed out
```

But Gatling seems to fail, above 1000 rps. Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure but "_handshake timed out_" seemed to mean that your server-side can't handle this flood of incoming HTTP*S* connections and thus client starts to fail with timeouts

Comment: @SergGr But tried it with Stormrunner and it works.